# jedi dependency issue for spyder with Anaconda after upgrading to IPython 6.0

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I'm using spyder with Anaconda platform. I recently upgraded to IPython 6.0. Then when I opened up spyder, I got the following weird error:

[image: jedi dependency error]

I checked the dependencies and confirmed the weirdness:

[image: dependencies]

Why is the required field `=0.9.0` and not `>=0.9.0`? This issue is affecting the internal console and the other IPython consoles I opened in spyder. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) Unfortunately, the current release of Spyder (i.e. **3.1.3**) is not compatible with Jedi 0.10, that's the problem.

However, we're about to release **3.1.4**, which will be compatible with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any approximate release date?

Comment: Yes, tomorrow or Sunday at most.